# C# Compiler - IO Activity

Tags: c#, io, compilation

We've been having a debate at work regarding .net project structure and related compiler workload.

I stand in the corner of the more .net projects you have, the more dependencies between projects you have the more work you're asking the compiler to do. My argument is centered around the amount of I/O involved during compilation when there are more projects. Someone at work suggests that the number of projects isn't related to the compile time. Needless to say I've had to bite my tongue for the time being as I don't have empirical evidence to hand, just experience that tells me I'm correct.

Whilst I have lots of other opinions about the many motivations for separating code into different .net projects typically being a fallacy or none logical, I'm actually just trying to find authoritative, empirical evidence to either support me or tell me I'm wrong.

I've looked around and am struggling to find a recent (or otherwise) comprehensive article on it.

Any help on the matter would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks
Tim

Edit : For the avoidance of doubt I'm talking about the same amount of code split over more projects, not more code over more projects.

Comment: More projects = more code = more compiling... How is this difficult?

Comment: + more dependency resolution as well; we had to reduce the amount of projects as our build server was taking too long. It's actually quite easy to prove: set up two demo solutions and time them building.

Comment: Do you mean "same code, divided among a greater number of projects"? I think that's clearly implied (the question is too obvious to ask otherwise), but you never know.

Comment: This is way too broad for SO... There is no replacement to measure your particular case and decide. Notes to think about: disk reads are cached - unless your machines have tiny amount of RAM reading same dependency multiple times not going to matter much, the only real way to speed things up is not to do them:) - if solution is too big splitting it into multiple separate builds and pushing dependencies to others (i.e. via NuGet) will likely speed up each particular build.

Comment: performace (compilation speed in this case) cannot be determined by thought, only by measuring. So set up some tests and measure

Comment: I think a big factor here is that as code changes only changed projects are recompiled as well as dependents. Many smaller projects can save time in the long run even if a full rebuild takes longer

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. I agree that there's no substitution in debate for example or empirical evidence. Whilst I can (and now will) throw something together I was originally wondering if there was an authoritative example on it already available. As is often the case, debates can be won/lost on the strength of credible evidence rather than anecdotes, though my own personal experience is as per the general opinion (more projects (with same amount of code) = longer compiles)